# How can I limit the results extracted by a query in Acces?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have this query in my Access database:

```
SELECT t_Campioni_CAMPIONE, t_Campioni.[DATA ARRIVO], t_Campioni.PRODUTTORE, t_Campioni.CodF, t_Fornitori.[Nome Fornitore]
FROM t_Campioni INNER JOIN t_Fornitori ON t_Campioni.CodF = t_Fornitori.CodF
WHERE (((t_Campioni.CAMPIONE)=[Forms]![m_Campioni_modifica]![CAMPIONE]))
ORDER BY t_Campioni.[DATA ARRIVO] DESC;
```

It works but I need it to extract only the first record (with the last date). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your initial `SELECT` by `SELECT TOP 1`

```
SELECT TOP 1 t_Campioni_CAMPIONE, t_Campioni.[DATA ARRIVO], t_Campioni.PRODUTTORE, t_Campioni.CodF, t_Fornitori.[Nome Fornitore]
FROM t_Campioni INNER JOIN t_Fornitori ON t_Campioni.CodF = t_Fornitori.CodF
WHERE (((t_Campioni.CAMPIONE)=[Forms]![m_Campioni_modifica]![CAMPIONE]))
ORDER BY t_Campioni.[DATA ARRIVO] DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t_Campioni_CAMPIONE, t_Campioni.[DATA ARRIVO], t_Campioni.PRODUTTORE,    
t_Campioni.CodF, t_Fornitori.[Nome Fornitore]
FROM t_Campioni INNER JOIN t_Fornitori ON t_Campioni.CodF = t_Fornitori.CodF
WHERE (((t_Campioni.CAMPIONE)=[Forms]![m_Campioni_modifica]![CAMPIONE]))
ORDER BY t_Campioni.[DATA ARRIVO] DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TOP/LIMIT/ROWNUM` depends on your RDBM. 
For more info: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp